# TideSDK 1.3.1-beta Installation on Windows XP

Tags: tidesdk

After successfully installing TideSDK 1.3.1-beta and Developer 1.4.2 on my Windows 7 machine, I thought I would have no problem installing on my older Windows XP laptop.  I have:
1: Downloaded and extracted the Tide 1.3.1-beta (Windows) to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\TideSDK  -- three big folders, sdk, runtime, and modules.
2: Installed WIX and ImageMagick
3: Downloaded Developer 1.4.2 
4: Downloaded Hello-World app

When I fire up TideSDK developer and attempt to import the Hello World Project, I get a TideSDK Developer (1.4.2) popup window saying  "You are importing a desktop project, but no Desktop SDK versions exist on your system"

What am I overlooking?  Some PATH requirement or .dll installation or install application for the SDK (other than simply extracting to the location given above)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  (I love TideSDK)

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both previous answer-suppliers.  My own solution is the following:

By searching in the C:\Program Files\TideSDK Developer folder and sub-folders for the phrase "no Desktop SDK versions" I found where the alert comes from -- Line 1666 in C:\Program Files\TideSDK Developer\Resources\perspectives\projects\js\projects.js.  In the code, I noticed that the alert results from a empty result from a call to Ti.Project.getSDKVersions(). By perusing the TideSDK API docs, I determined that getSDKVersions() relies on a call to Ti.API.getComponentSearchPaths().  When I inserted
    alert (Ti.API.getComponentSearchPaths()); at Line 1665, the result was two PATHS -- One was C:\Documents and Settings[my current user]\Application Data\TideSDK and the other was

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\TideSDK

NOTE:  All Users.WINDOWS,  rather than All Users.  So, I copied the TideSDK folder to the above location (and removed the Hidden attribute, as suggested above) and now Developer finds TideSDK and all is well.

I don't know if the above solution applies to ALL TideSDK installations on Windows XP or not, but if anyone has been receiving the  "You are importing a desktop project, but no Desktop SDK versions exist on your system" alert in TideSDK Developer on XP, I suggest giving this a try.

Jonathan
(neologis)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, you have to unzip the contents of TideSDK into C:\ProgramData\TideSDK

C:\ProgramData is a hidden folder, so you have to make it unhide and then unzip the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are strictly following the Getting Started Guide at: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

It seems that the SDK has not been extracted at correct place so Developer is not finding it.

The Step you should be looking in the guide would be:

STEP 1: Download and extract the SDK

Comment: Hi Mital:Thank you for the rapid response.  I had been following the Getting Started Guide, but I started from scratch and did the SDK extraction to the folder listed for Windows XP, again.  I notice that there is an "installer"  in  ...tidesdk\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\installer. Trying to run this installer, directly, doesn't work: "Installation failed. The installer could not determine the application path."  Is there an installation routine (more than just extracting the files) required to install the SDK?  Where does the installer look to find the "application path?"

Comment: That installer is not expected to work.. but of you extract the sdk to correct path it should pickup.

Check your hello world manifest file uses 1.3.1-beta as versions of different modules.